# pipeline("|")-key alternative on Memo Leste

Tags: pipe, keyboard-layout, arm

I don't have a `|`-key.

is there an alternative to it?

say, can I execute an equivalent to `dmesg | less` if I can't type `|`?

---

**System**

```
# uname -a  
Linux devuan-droid4 5.4.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jan 12 19:38:25 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**Hardware**
[image]
[Droid 4](https://leste.maemo.org/images/2/2e/Motorola-Droid4-20200125.jpeg)

---

**Update based on comments**

```
# setxkbmap -query   
rules:     evdev     
model:     pc105    
layout:    us
```

```
# setxkbmap -print    
xkb_keymap {
     xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(querty)" };    
     xkb_types     { include "complete" };    
     xkb_compat    { include "complete" };    
     xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };    
     xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105" };
};
```

---

Update 2024
The issue went away by the developers. Here is [their wiki](https://leste.maemo.org/Motorola_Droid_4#Notes)

Comment: I recently had to return a keyboard because it didn't come with a `|` key, if you plan to code things I suggest you do the same.  You can remap it to another key but the company that made your keyboard should not go unpunished.  This aggression against the pipe key will not stand man.

Comment: I'm sure it's on some other key. On my keyboard, the `|` can be found on a key with the two symbols `~` and `#` (with `Shift` depressed; without shift I get a backslash).  Also, in it's current form, this question is hardly Unix related, but more a question for SuperUser, IMHO.

Comment: Are you using gnome?

Comment: thanx for the comments, I have updated the info to clarify the scenario

Comment: On my similarly looking old Nokia N810, I've bound it to FN+Z (the yen symbol, ~ the same position as SYM-Z on your device) via a file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. You have to decide on key combo, that's certainly possible in Debian/Devuan, too.

Comment: @mosvy: thanx! ... `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` is a directory. mapping must be possoble, but I still don't know how to do it...

Comment: Does `Shift+Alt+,` work?  Found here: https://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-enter-a-pipe-symbol.15824/ after [a basic web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=droid4+pipe+symbol+keyboard).

Comment: Please show the output of `setxkbmap -query`, and post somewhere the output of `setxkbmap -print`.

Comment: @jesse_b: unfortunately no.

Comment: @Kusalananda: no

Comment: @Kusalananda that's not android

Comment: @mosvy Oh well.

Comment: @mosvy: updated :)

Comment: I was meaning "the output of `xkbcomp $DISPLAY -`", sorry (which can be quite big, >2000 lines). You can even test it by `xkbcomp $DISPLAY file; ... edit file; xkbcomp file $DISPLAY` before modifying the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file.

Comment: If you have a solution to your issue, then add it as a proper answer.  Otherwise we'll close this question as "problem went away".

Comment: @Kusalananda: the problem went away

Answer (score 2):

Alternative 1:

It is not a general substitute for | but will work in some cases:

```
less <(dmesg)
```

Alternative 2 (requires \):

```
perl -e 'print "I=\"".chr(124)."\"\n"' >> .bashrc
```

Alternative 3:

```
perl -e 'print "I=".'"'"'"'"'"'.chr(124).'"'"'"'"'"'.'"'                                               
'"  >> .bashrc
```

Alternative 4: Edit .bashrc and type (e.g. by doing `cat >> .bashrc`):

```
I=$(perl -e 'print chr(124)')
```

Start a new bash, and then you can run:

```
eval dmesg $I grep Linux $I less
```

Comment: nice option! I don't have an internet connection working on this device... but there might be a `|` somewhere in the system files, right?

Comment: oh, I unfortunately also don't have a backslash...

Comment: wow, so many options!.. ehm.. alternative 2 requires __ what?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the > key, you could try :

```
dmesg > dmesg.txt
less dmesg.txt
```

Comment: I have that key, it is a workaround :) ... but is there a replacement?